# How to secure localstorage? Offline access to app

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

There is a lot of topics about localstorage and how to secure it but i didnt found 100% offline solution(I dont know if its even possible).

My app is using ionic framework + ng-token-auth + devise-token-auth.

I have authentication stuff in it.

All I really want to store in localstorage are photos but those photos belongs to particular user...

I want to make my app working offline also, so my idea is to create localPassword value(random) in registration procedure and then return this value to the client-side and save it locally.

I will use that value to encode photos using AES encryption(propably forge) and store this value locally. This value will be updating on every sign_in() procedure and it will be destroyed at sign_out().

In case when internet connection will be lost and authentication will be unable than I open my app and show decoded photos using this localPassword, that are belonging to the last logged user.

1. Should I care about that kind of stuff -Decoding enconding photos or should I just show photos of last logged user
2. Does it even make sense ? I want to make accessing photos difficult outside the app and I want to make my app working offline(offering little functionality of adding/editing photos)

sorry for bad english, thanks for any advice !

Comment: I would think emptying local storage on log out would be just as secure as having to encrypt/decrypt the photo. encrypting it and decrypting it client-side doesn't really add any security, if someone wants to get to it maliciously and they have access to the encrypted data and the javascript (which generally will be the case,) they should be able to reverse engineer the js enough to decrypt it.

Comment: but what if I want to keep my photos locally, i dont want to download them on every log in and destroy them on every sign out

Comment: Encrypting them with the key being client-side won't make that any more "secure". There is no good solution here if your goal is to keep the photos available offline AND prevent unauthenticated users from viewing them, unless you delete them when the user is no longer authenticated.